# Chaining Sequential Request Handlers based on the response recieved by each

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to set up nginx in way that it could handle multiple request handlers in sequence depending on the response it provides.

1. Request Received
2. Check if cached in-Memory nginx if yes return if No goto 3
3. Check if Redis has this request if yes return if No goto 4
4. Go to Reverse Proxy Upstream Server and return
5. As non blocking operation save response data in redis(in-memory cache will be updated as it is)

Reason of Going to Redis is that I will have data saved in various structures in Redis and could retrieve data out of these various structures and then merge these chunks from Redis keys' process it back to send the actual .

The input/output is XML.

Comment: What has this to do with Lua?

Comment: Th basic solutions that I had in mind were to use Lua based extensions and thought would be something suggestive here from LUA community as such.

Comment: Then you should specify what extension you'd use and show some research effort in that field, and maybe tentative code. Otherwise the **Lua** (this is the right spelling, it is not an acronym, it means "Moon" in Portuguese) tag is utterly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Step 3, 4, 5 can be achieved by using ngx_srcache + ngx_redis/ngx_redis2:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSRCacheModule

while step 2 can be done via the rewrite_by_lua directive of ngx_lua in the same location:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#rewrite_by_lua

The step 1 is always done by the Nginx core anyway :)

If you can access your HTTP backend service via ngx_lua's cosocket API, then all these steps can be done completely in Lua (in ngx_lua's [content_by_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#content_by_lua)). You'll need the [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/agentzh/lua-resty-redis) to access Redis nonblockingly and [lua-resty-http-simple](https://github.com/bakins/lua-resty-http-simple) (for example) to access the remote HTTP services.